# comparing enum value with enum instance

Tags: c

Why can't it be done like this?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct test
    {
        value z;
        int x;
    };

    main()
    {
        enum value {a,b,c,d};
        struct test come;
        come.z = 2;
        if (a == z) printf("they match ");
        else printf("dont match");
    }
```

Comment: @Muggen is there any other way to do this

Comment: look at Lundin's answer and maybe you will find that interesting : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the enum a typedef enum and place it above the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum { a,b,c,d } value;

struct test
{
  value z;
  int x;
};

int main()
{
  struct test come;
  come.z = 2;

  if (a == come.z)
    printf("they match ");
  else
    printf("dont match");
}
```

Edit: fixed some minor typos.

Comment: +1 but just to clarify: you do not *need* to `typedef` the `enum` for this to work. The important point for the OP is that the definition of the `enum` must appear before it is used in the `struct test` definition.

Comment: @GrahamS You do need to typedef it, or otherwise you would have to declare the enum inside the struct, which makes the code harder to read.

Comment: You can leave the enum where you have it, but declare it as `enum value {a,b,c,d}` instead. Then you use it in the `struct` as `enum value x;`

Comment: @GrahamS Fair enough =)  I still avoid using two word types though, because C is about the only language that allows two words for one type. So if I had written this code myself, I would have typedef:ed the struct as well.

Comment: yeah I agree and I'd usually `typedef` it too if I was writing the code myself, as it makes using it a lot neater. However the salient point for @asir is that the compiler reads the code from the top to the bottom - if it gets to the `value z;` in the `struct` declaration before you tell it what `value` is, then it does not know what to do. So the definition of `value` *must* appear before the `struct` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to `#include <stdlib.h>`
- `value` is undefined
- `z` by itself does not exist. It exists only as a member of `struct test`

This works (I've added whitespace, removed stdlib, changed `value` to `int`, added return type and parameters info to main, changed the `z` inside the if, added '\n' to the prints, and added `return 0;`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test
{
    int z;
    int x;
};

int main(void)
{
    enum value {a, b, c, d};
    struct test come;
    come.z = 2;
    if (a == come.z) printf("they match\n");
    else printf("don't match\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The definition of `enum value` really should be outside any function.